# Borrar un string en base a condiciones con python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Quiero hacer lo siguiente en `python`*(pyspark)*

Tengo un `RDD` y necesito crear una función que borre un string en base a unas condiciones para después aplicar esa función al `RDD` completo.

Debo conseguir con la función borrar las líneas del RDD que no usen los caracteres: `9,1,%,A`

Pongo el ejemplo:

```
def borrar(estr):

    if line in ('9','1','%','A'):
        return True
    elif line not in ('9','1','%','A'):
        return False
```

Tengo esto, y me devuelve si es True o False si le paso un string. Pero lo que quiero es que lo borre y que se pueda aplicar al RDD. No consigo pasar de aquí :(

RDD:

```
91
92%76
93$234
9A
9%
BC
```

El resultado después de aplicar la función al RDD debería ser:
RDD:

```
91
9A
9%
```

Espero haberme explicado.Gracias.

Comment: Del RDD todas las líneas excepto la última utilizan al menos uno de los caracteres que dices, ¿por qué no deberían salir la línea 2 y 3?

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, la razón es que quiero eliminar todas las filas que lleven algún caracter que no sea '9','1','%' o 'A'

Answer (score 1):

Si te entendido bién lo que necesitas es una función que retorne `True` si una cadena **solo contiene** '9', '1', '%' y 'A' y `False` si contiene cualquier carácter diferente.

Para ello lo más simple es recorrer la cadena y ver si alguno de los caracteres no pertenece a ese conjunto usando un break para implementar un short-circuit y no evaluar siempre toda la cadena:

```
def filtro(cadena):
    validas = set(('9','1','%','A'))
    for letra in cadena:
        if letra not in validas:
            return False
    return True
```

Una forma más simple y que también implementa short-cicuit  es usar `any` o `all`:

```
def filtro(cadena):
    return all(letra in ('9','1','%','A') for letra in cadena):
```

La tercera forma es usar expresiones regulares con patrones negativos:

```
import re

def filtro(cadena):
    return  not re.search('[^91A\%]', cadena)
```

Las tres funciones retornan `True` con '91', '9A', '9%' y `False` con el resto. En Spark puedes aplicar la fiunción directamente usando `map` y `lambda` sobre el RDD o usarla para crear un filtro boleano.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer eso en py-spark puede aplicar withColumn para reemplazar cada columna removiendo el string mediante regexp_replace simplemente reemplazando con ''

```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    df.withColumn(<tu_columna_str>, regexp_replace(<tu_columna_str>, <str_a_remover>, <str_a_reemplazar>))
```